# Characterize all left-module of some matrix ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ be the ring of formal power series and $S=M_2(R)$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices of entries in $R$.

Then characterize all finitely generated left-modules on $S$ and their endomorphism rings.

I know that $R$ is a PID and also Noetherian. Is there some similar results about left-modules like the well-known 'stucture of finitely generated module over PID' ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is known that $M_2(R)$ is Morita equivalent to $R$. So, studying finitely generated left $S$-modules is equivalent to studying finitely generated left $R$-modules.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang This looks like a brand new theory to me. In fact, this problem comes from our qualification exam. Would you please provide a proof or a direct reference? Thanks a lot!